# How to set display:none on a parent element if child component is not present in Angular 9?

Tags: angular

I would like to embed some of my twitter posts into the site. I put embed HTML provided from Twitter into the site and then call `window.twttr.widgets.load()` that adds style and tweet to the embed HTML. User sees this transition from plain to Twitter style. I would like to perform this transition in the background by using `display: none` and then show the already styled Tweet post . The post is rendered when `twitter-widget` element is present.

Suppose I have:

```html
 <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <div
        #twitterPost
        class="post"
        [style.display]="hasChild() ? 'block' : 'none'"
      >
        <div [innerHTML]="post.EmbedHTML"></div>
 </div>
```

`hasChild()` should detect when `twitter-widget` element is present in the `.post`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" [style.display]="hasChild() ? 'block' : 'none'">
      <div
        #twitterPost
        class="post">
        <div [innerHTML]="post.EmbedHTML"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How to implement `hasChild()` function properly?